# how to block range port to dest port with some flags in iptables

Tags: networking, iptables

I need to block (in localnet) all traffic coming from a specific range of ports to another port, with specific flags

**Traffic:**

```
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 50800, Dst Port: 443, Seq: 1, Ack: 1, Len: 179
Source Port: 50800
Destination Port: 443
[Stream index: 1]
[TCP Segment Len: 179]
Sequence number: 1    (relative sequence number)
[Next sequence number: 180    (relative sequence number)]
Acknowledgment number: 1    (relative ack number)
0101 .... = Header Length: 20 bytes (5)
Flags: 0x018 (PSH, ACK)
    000. .... .... = Reserved: Not set
    ...0 .... .... = Nonce: Not set
    .... 0... .... = Congestion Window Reduced (CWR): Not set
    .... .0.. .... = ECN-Echo: Not set
    .... ..0. .... = Urgent: Not set
    .... ...1 .... = Acknowledgment: Set
    .... .... 1... = Push: Set
    .... .... .0.. = Reset: Not set
    .... .... ..0. = Syn: Not set
    .... .... ...0 = Fin: Not set
    [TCP Flags: ·······AP···]
Window size value: 64400
[Calculated window size: 64400]
[Window size scaling factor: -2 (no window scaling used)]
Checksum: 0x1bcb [unverified]
[Checksum Status: Unverified]
Urgent pointer: 0
[SEQ/ACK analysis]
    [iRTT: 0.212323000 seconds]
    [Bytes in flight: 179]
    [Bytes sent since last PSH flag: 179]
[Timestamps]
TCP payload (179 bytes)
```

**failed attempts:**

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i eth1 -p tcp --sport 49152:65535 --dport 443 --tcp-flags PSH ACK -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
```

or with combinations:

```
--tcp-flags PSH, ACK
--tcp-flags PSH,ACK PSH
```

or forward and input:

```
iptables -I INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp --sport 49152:65535 --dport 443 --tcp-flags PSH,ACK PSH -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD -i eth1 -p tcp --sport 49152:65535 --dport 443 --tcp-flags PSH,ACK PSH -j DROP
```

**Question:**

How do I block this traffic with iptables rule? (Described in 'traffic')

PD: Sources consulted http://ask.wireshark.org/questions/20423/pshack-wireshark-capture

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the chain on which to set the rule is determined by whether or not the connection is made to your local box. If it's supposed to end there, you'd choose INPUT. If you need to pass the traffic on to another box, you'd use FORWARD. Second, you have to add `-m tcp` to your rule for `--tcp-flags` to have an effect. Now, depending on what to filter, you need to set your flags accordingly. If you are just going for the PSH flag (and want to ignore the rest), `--tcp-flags PSH PSH` is entirely sufficient. If you need to go for PSH/ACK, you have to set it as `--tcp-flags PSH,ACK PSH,ACK` to get both into the check. Your `--tcp-flags PSH,ACK PSH` checks for a set PSH flag and a cleared ACK flag.

As for `--tcp-flags PSH ACK`, that is never going to produce a positive result, because you state to examine the PSH flag, but then actually check for ACK instead. However, since you are ignoring that, there's no way for the match to become true.

**Explanation:**

If you read through `man iptables-extensions`, you are going to find that `--tcp-flags` takes two arguments: A flag mask and a flag value. The first parameter tells the tcp match which flags to examine whereas the second tells it which ones of those you want to see set (the remainder of  the examined flags has to be cleared in the packet). If the packte matches your condition, you score a hit and the rule has an effect. If not, that's a miss and the rule is ignored.

Comment: Your explanation is very illustrative, and I appreciate it, but I would like you to be more specific and answer the question. Thanks in advance

Comment: That would have to wait until I'm back at home. Here at work I don't have access to my computer.